# Getting Error in Databricks :Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfiguration

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

```
dependencies {
  compile('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.2.1'){
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module : "guava"
    }
    
    // Azure storage dependencies
    compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.7.0'
    
    // HBase
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-client', version: '1.6.0'
    
    compile group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-core', version: '3.3.5.RELEASE' , force: true
    compile group: 'io.projectreactor.netty', name: 'reactor-netty', version: '0.9.7.RELEASE', force: true
    
    
    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-transport', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true
       compile (group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-codec-http', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true){
            exclude group: 'io.netty', module: 'netty-codec'
        }
        compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-common', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true
        compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-handler', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true
        compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-transport-native-epoll', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true
        compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-resolver', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true
        compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-buffer', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true
        compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-transport-native-unix-common', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true
        compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-codec', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true
       compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.49.Final', force: true
        
    
}
```

This is spark cluster dependency . I have removed netty versions. But still in databricks it fails. I checked the jar also, it contains handler.

```
dependencies {
    // Spark dependency.
    compile( group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.4.5')
    {
        exclude group: "io.netty", module : "netty"
        exclude group: "io.netty", module : "netty-all"
    }
   

    // Spark for SQL and parquet file.
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.5'

    compile group: 'com.esotericsoftware', name: 'kryo', version: '4.0.2'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.8'

    compile group: 'org.codehaus.janino', name: 'janino', version: '3.1.2'

    // Gson
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'

    // Java tuple for Pair.
    compile group: 'org.javatuples', name: 'javatuples', version: '1.2'

    // Lombok dependency
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Getting issue of could not initialise. Please let me know what I am missing . I can see in dependency tree that new version of netty handler is getting used

```js
20/09/13 18:57:43 ERROR Schedulers: Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslProvider.isAlpnSupported(Lio/netty/handler/ssl/SslProvider;)Z
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientSecure.<clinit>(HttpClientSecure.java:79)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:301)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.resubscribe(FluxRetryPredicate.java:124)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryPredicate.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryPredicate.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:326)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelaySubscription.accept(MonoDelaySubscription.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelaySubscription.accept(MonoDelaySubscription.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDelaySubscription$DelaySubscriptionOtherSubscriber.onNext(FluxDelaySubscription.java:123)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: At least put initial part, and lines “caused by”

Comment: Added in the snippet above

Comment: I followed this page also. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#dependency-conflict                                                                    
 Tried creating shadow jar /fat jar.. But it doesnt take netty handler '4.1.49.Final'

Comment: @AlexOtt please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: let's get to the basic question - what do you want to achieve at the end? What programming language do you use? What Databricks Runtime do you use? etc.